# What is the best practice to implement methods using values of properties in the View Model?

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, viewmodel, windows-community-toolkit

I am currently developing a UWP application, but I think this question applies to any project type with a UI. I have built a View Model for my UI using the new Microsoft Toolkit MVVM library. It has properties such as:

```
        private bool _isLoginAvailable = true;     
        public bool IsLoginAvailable
        {
            get => _isLoginAvailable;
            set => SetProperty(ref _isLoginAvailable, value);
        }
```

Furthermore, I have a few business methods that as parameters require up to 5-6 of these properties.

Reading on forums, I saw that it is unadvised to business logic within the view model, therefore, I came up with the following options:

1. Create a new class for the methods, and use the view model as a parameter: `SampleMethod(SampleViewModel vm)`. Then, if I create an object of this class in the view model, I could use `SampleMethod(this)`. At this point, I don't really see a difference between this option, and including the method within the view model class.
2. Second option I see is to add each required parameter to the method, and return each parameter as well in a tuple: `SampleMethod(var1, var2, var3...) { return (var1, var2, var3...)}` This to me seems very cumbersome.
3. The third option I figured is to use the MVVM Toolkit's messaging feature. In this case, I can set up the constructor of the view model to listen to messages with  `Messenger.Register<SampleViewModel, Var1Message>(this, (r, m) => r.var1 = m.Value);`. Then, the method in a differenct class can send the value in message using `Messenger.Send(new Var1Message(message)`. While this seems to be the best option, as it can be easily implemented together with dependency injection, it quickly becomes very convoluted, as for each property a new sealed class is required, that describes the message.

Is any of these options the best practice, or is there an option that I am not aware of?

Comment: "I saw that it is unadvised to include methods within the view model". Eh? As a stand alone statement that makes no sense. VM's can contain as many methods as you want. Do you mean they should not contain _business_ logic methods as opposed to view logic?

Comment: Can you provide a source to why it is unadvised to include methods within the viewmodel?

Comment: Where you put the business logic is a design decision. Some people add a contoller instance to M-V-VM, some put all the logic in the VM. Some to the Model. Some have an additional BL layer. It's your own choice.

Comment: If the method works on properties of the VM, you don't need to pass anything. 
I would leave the method in the same VM class that owns the methods you work on.
If you copy all the state to the next VM just to separate methods from properties all you get is code bloat.

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer, indeed, what I meant is business logic.

Comment: @JonasH I edited the question, so that it is more clear, that what I meant is business logic and not methods related to the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If business methods require multiple properties in your VM, then maybe the properties should be in the business object? Are the properties intrinsic to the business rules, or do they only exist in the context of the view?

VM properties can just pass through to the business properties, or quite often you can just directly expose the business object itself in your VM.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Indeed even though these properties exist on the UI as well, they are mainly related to business logic, therefore they should be in that class. Then, in the view model, the get and set accessors can be used to access the property in the business logic, right?

Comment: @BalazsSzekeres exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that its inadvisable to use methods within a ViewModel?

A ViewModel must act as an intermediary between the View, Model and business logic classes or libraries.

Consider using a RelayCommand (implement the property as ICommand type) in your ViewModel, this can be bound to a button click and is used to call a method within your ViewModel that takes the property values and passes them to your business logic.

A typical scenario for a ViewModel may be user input on a form, with your ViewModel properties being bound by the View. The user then clicks a button to submit this data.

Comment: The RelayCommand was already implemented in my view model. To "make a method that takes the property values and passes them to your business logic", sounds similar to what I mentioned in option 2. Is that what you meant, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Not really as you talk about returning a tuple value, in a way that implies all of the property values as separate items. MVVM Toolkit SetProperty is cumbersome in that it requires an individual field value even if the value itself comes from a multi-property Model class. The Model is then passed to the business logic. I prefer not to embed business logic within my ViewModel as it is easier to unit test and mock that way (both the business logic and the ViewModel).